# Trying to set jquery to fire once after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to fire jquery only once when resizing? I have here a script that adds a `hash(#)` within the `href` of an `anchor <a>` element. The problem is the script keeps when resizing and so it keeps adding `hash` within the `href`. Is there a way to make it fire only once?

```
(function($){
    'use strict';



    var mobileMenuDrawer = {

        init : function() {

            $('.region-primary-menu').addClass('primary-mobile-menu');
            $('.primary-mobile-menu .menu.-primary > .menu-item').addClass('mobile-menu-item');
            $('.primary-mobile-menu .menu.-primary > .mobile-menu-item > .link').off('click').on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('.mobile-menu-item').toggleClass('-active');
            })
        },

        clear : function() {
            $('.primary-mobile-menu, .mobile-menu-item').removeClass('primary-mobile-menu mobile-menu-item');
        }
    }

    var addHash = {

        init : function() {

            if ($('.region-primary-menu').hasClass('primary-mobile-menu')) {

                $('.primary-mobile-menu .mobile-menu-item > .link').each(function() {
                    // console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                    let currentUrl = $(this).attr('href');

                    $(this).prop('href', '#' + currentUrl);

                    // this.href = '/#/' + this.href;
                    // window.location.hash     = $(this).attr('href');
                });
            }

            else {

                $('.primary-mobile-menu .mobile-menu-item > .link').each(function() {

                    $(this).removeAttr('#');

                });

            }
        }
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($(window).outerWidth() <= 1024) {
            mobileMenuDrawer.init();
        }

        else {
            mobileMenuDrawer.clear();
        }

        addHash.init();


    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        if ($(window).outerWidth() <= 1024) {
            mobileMenuDrawer.init();
            addHash.init();
        }

        else {
            mobileMenuDrawer.clear();
        }
    });



})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just put a flag checking if the property already exists:

```
if(!$(this).prop('href')) {
    $(this).prop('href', '#' + currentUrl);
}
```

Or if the property is similar:

```
if($(this).prop('href') != '#' + currentUrl) {
    $(this).prop('href', '#' + currentUrl);
}
```

Or if the property is empty (will only work if the property already exists):

```
if($(this).prop('href') == "") {
    $(this).prop('href', '#' + currentUrl);
}
```

---

If you want to prevent the entire codeblock from executing. You could use some sort of custom flag that you need to flick to the opposite boolean value once a desired operation has been completed. You could make this a variable in your local function scope or make it a property of the `addHash` object. I'll do the former in this one.

```
 let isOk = false;

 var addHash = {

    init : function() {
        if(isOk) return;

        if ($('.region-primary-menu').hasClass('primary-mobile-menu')) {

            $('.primary-mobile-menu .mobile-menu-item > .link').each(function() {
                let currentUrl = $(this).attr('href');

                $(this).prop('href', '#' + currentUrl);
                isOk = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: You should stop using var.

Comment: I tried the first solution by adding a `flag` or `condition`, but it still keeps on adding a `hash` when I tried resizing. Made a `jsfiddle` you could check on it. http://jsfiddle.net/eof8kpsj/

Comment: What I'm just trying resolve here is just to figure out how I can fire the script only once when the window is being resize below `1024px` so it stops adding `hash` to the `href`

Comment: @clestcruz I edited a bit and any of my solutions should now work.

Comment: Your second solution has an extra parentheses `()` I'm trying out the second solution and is still adds `hash` which is weird since the purpose of the `flag` is to check the value